# How can I create a phosphor screen effect like this one in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blend-modes

I would like to create an effect like the one in the picture but I'm a noob.

The idea is like the light in a phosphor screen that reveals it's pixels.
I guess there's a texture layer and some sort of blend mode involved but I don't know if the texture is above or below the light and how to solve this. Can anybody give a hint to reproduce something like this?

[image: screen revealing its pixels]

Thank you

Comment: But it isn't a snippet of CRT screen image, it's a drawing or from something else than from a CRT display.See how smooth and sharp the yellow curve is, much sharper than the existing screen pixels would make possible.

Comment: Yes, it's a drawing but I want to do something similar and I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a brush stroke with some layer effects applied, such as an outer glow and drop shadow, then add a layer above with a pattern fill and reduced opacity.  Then brighten everything up with a curves adjustment on top

Something like this:

[image]

The pattern I used looks like this

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! This is just what I wanted. Thank you very  much.